# How to programmatically check view permission to a url in SharePoint?

Tags: permissions

Is there a way to find out whether a particular user has permissions to view a given sharepoint url. I tried to use the [DoesUserHavePermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441848.aspx) method, but the problem is that I am not sure what object does the url points to (item/list/web/site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure but can try creating an HttpWebRequest for the target URI and POST some data. Depending whether the user has rights ot not, an exception will be thrown which you can further handle to code and conclude accordingly.

http://authors.aspalliance.com/stevesmith/articles/netscrape2.asp